# Retrive information from list associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Hy,

how I retrieve information from an associative array like list in php.

var_dump shows something like this:

```
array(2) { [1]=> string(1) "1" 
           [2]=> string(1) "2" } 
array(2) { [1]=> string(15) "gica_craioveanu" 
           [2]=> string(14) "alexandra_minu" } 
array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "craiovaMAX" 
           [1]=> string(10) "alexMinu10" }
```

First array containd the id's, second the user name and third the passwords.

My attempt:

```
    foreach ($row as $i => $id,$user_name,$user_pass) {
        echo "<tr>\n" .
          "  <td>".var_dump($id)."</td>\n".
          "  <td>".var_dump($user_name)."</td>\n".
           "  <td>".var_dump($user_pass)."</td>\n".
          " </tr>\n"
    }

one of php file contains the script to construct the list:

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
/*$id[]=$row['user_id'];
$user_name[]=$row['user_name'];
$user_pass[]=$row['user_pass'];
$i=$i+1;*/
list($id[$i],$user_name[$i],$user_pass[$i++])=$row;
}
/*for($no=0; $no<$i; $no++){
            echo $row[$i]."/".$row[$i]."/";
}*/
include 'user.html.php';
}
?>
```

and the user.html.php

to view the rows:

```
    <?php 
    //   while (list($id, $user_name, $user_pass)= each($row)) {
    foreach($row as $i => $id,$user_name,$user_pass){

    echo " <tr>\n" .
          "  <td>".$id."</td>\n".
          "  <td>".$user_name."</td>\n".
           "  <td>".$user_pass."</td>\n".
          " </tr>\n";

/*echo "<tr>\n" .
          "  <td>".var_dump($id)."</td>\n".
          "  <td>".var_dump($user_name)."</td>\n".
           "  <td>".var_dump($user_pass)."</td>\n".
          " </tr>\n"
          */

          /*for($no=0; $no<$i; $no++){
            echo "<tr>".
            "<td>".$row[$i]."</td>".
            "<td>".$row[$i]."</td>".
            "<td>".$row[$i]."</td>".
            "</tr>";*/
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: foreach item in array... What have you tried ?

Comment: Not what you have, what have you **tried**?

Comment: @SocketM array_merge then.. and work with them that way

Comment: foreach($row as $i => $id,$user_name,$user_pass){
 
    echo " <tr>\n" .
          "  <td>".$id."</td>\n".
          "  <td>".$user_name."</td>\n".
     "  <td>".$user_pass."</td>\n".
          " </tr>\n";

Comment: i it is a counter that i have used for the rows of the database

Comment: i have tried a for loop:

Comment: for($no=0; $no<$i; $no++){
   echo "<tr>".
   "<td>".$row[$i]."</td>".
   "<td>".$row[$i]."</td>".
   "<td>".$row[$i]."</td>".
   "</tr>";*/

Comment: 1. Why do you have 3 arrays?
2. Why do the indexes start with "1" for 2 arrays and "0" for the third?
3. What is $row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) { 
    list($id[$i],$user_name[$i],$user_pass[$i++])=$row; 
}
```

...

```
for($i = 1; $i < count($id) + 1; $i++) {
    echo " <tr>\n" .
         "  <td>".$id[$i]."</td>\n".
         "  <td>".$user_name[$i]."</td>\n".
         "  <td>".$user_pass[($i - 1)]."</td>\n".
         " </tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: And if I want to live my script which is bringing me the list and only to acces its informations . The bellow scripts I want to remain as it is : while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
list($id[$i],$user_name[$i],$user_pass[$i++])=$row;
}

Comment: Then I would say, that your script has some serious problems regarding code quality. Anyway, I edited my answer. See above.

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in 

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 :-(

Comment: Please write down a shoert explanation in regard whith i=1 and user pass (i-1). Thank you :-)

Comment: You have 3 arrays. Two of them start with index "1", the third one starts with index "0". The loop starts with "1" to access the first items of the two arrays. To access the first item of the third array the value of $i has to be decreased by 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65161/discussion-between-socketm-and-typoheads).

Answer (score 1):

```
$id = array("1", "2");
$user_name = array("gica_craioveanu", "alexandra_minu");
$user_pass = array("craiovaMAX", "alexMinu10");
```

We presume that 3 arrays are always the same size :

```
// You make a loop on first array
for ( $i = 0 ; $i < count($id) ; $i++ )
{
    // You use index $i to access to 3 arrays.
    echo 'ID: '.$id[$i].'<br />';
    echo 'Name: '.$user_name[$i].'<br />';
    echo 'Password: '.$user_pass[$i].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: But all 3 array are inside a list named row.

Comment: You just have to change variables used. Answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($no=1; $no<$i+1; $no++)
          {
            echo "<tr>".
            "<td>".$id[$no]."</td>".
            "<td>".$user_name[$no]."</td>".
            "<td>".$user_pass[($no-1)]."</td>".
            "</tr>";
            }
```

Inspired by [Typoheads](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3446241/typoheads)